# dailyLimitExceededUnreg: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup

Tags: ruby, google-api

I set up a small script to export the first tab of a Google Sheet as csv via the Google Drive API. I can execute the script once and it works. During that execution I'm provided with a URL that let's me authenticate online and gives me a code. That code gets stored in a token.yaml file. Then the script successfully exports my sheet.

When I execute the script a second time, I get the error

```
dailyLimitExceededUnreg: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.
Continued use requires signup. (Google::Apis::ClientError)
```

When I delete the token.yaml file that was created during my first (successful) attempt, I can execute the script again, incl. authentication as described above. When I execute the script another time, I'm back to the error.

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v3'
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'
require 'fileutils'

OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'.freeze
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Maker'.freeze
CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'credentials.json'.freeze

FILE_ID = '<my-file-id>'

# The file token.yaml stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
#
# copied from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/ruby
TOKEN_PATH = 'token.yaml'.freeze
SCOPE = Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE

##
# Ensure valid credentials, either by restoring from the saved credentials
# files or initiating an OAuth2 authorization. If authorization is required,
# the user's default browser will be launched to approve the request.
#
# @return [Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials] OAuth2 credentials
#
# copied from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/ruby
def authorize
  client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file CREDENTIALS_PATH
  token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new file: TOKEN_PATH
  authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new client_id, SCOPE, token_store
  user_id = 'default'
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials user_id
  create_credentials(authorizer, user_id) if credentials.nil?
end

def create_credentials(authorizer, user_id)
  url = authorizer.get_authorization_url base_url: OOB_URI
  puts 'Open the following URL in the browser and enter the ' \
         "resulting code after authorization:\n" + url
  code = STDIN.gets
  authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code user_id: user_id,
                                                 code: code,
                                                 base_url: OOB_URI
end

# copied from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth
def download_csv
  service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
  service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
  service.authorization = authorize
  service.export_file(FILE_ID, 'text/csv') #only downloading first sheet
end

puts download_csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Google's quickstart example ( https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/ruby ) referenced their API version 0.8, which is outdated. There is a newer version 0.11. When I installed that, everything worked flawlessly.